# How to get POST parameters via node.js

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I a m kinda stuck. I made a request to a server. I want the server to computer a operation for me, and send me back the result.

Request :

```
    ar http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function(req, res){
        var response = "Hello from " + req.client.remoteAddress + ":" + req.client.remotePort + "\n to " +      req.client.localAddress + ":" + req.client.localPort;
        console.log(response);
        var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log("start");
    n = 15;
    const urlfibo='http://172.22.0.4:8899';
    Http.open("POST", urlfibo,false);
    var params = 'value=15';
    Http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    Http.send(params);
    console.log(Http.responseText);
    response +=  Http.responseText;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(response);


    res.end();
```

On my server, i don't know where to find the parameter i passed. I've tryed the solution in the doc, but my code is never running into it :

````
```

            response += "\n ON" + req.on
            let body = [];
            req.on('data', (chunk) => {
                response += "bla"
              body.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', () => {
              body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
              // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
            });
````

My question is : on y server (second part of code), how do i get my params i passed when i sent the request ? I want to do it with nodejs without using frameworks

Thank you

Comment: Doing all this stuff by hand is more trouble than it is worth. Use Express.js instead.

Comment: Hey Quentin =) I know i can use Express.js, but i'm trying to do it without using any framework in order to understand what is happening behind =)

Answer (score -1):

`chunk` will have all informations because is an object, you just have to assign this values for a new object and look for the parameters. Bug make sure to have in your code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser);
```

Comment: What is app? It looks like you are assuming they are using Express.js but there's no sign of that in the question.